# C# WPF does not release memory when i close window(which includes lots of image controls)

Tags: c#, wpf, memory

I have a window that includes lots of image controls(which displays some high quality images).

I added images in XAML like this:

```
<Image Name="Image" Source="Images/myimage.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
<Image Name="Image2" Source="Images/myimage2.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
<Image Name="Image3" Source="Images/myimage3.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
```

and goes like this.. As you see nothing fancy here. There isn't any code in code-behind.
This window just show these images and does not do anything else.

Because i'm displaying lots of high quality images, memory goes up like ~200mb.

When i close this window and open another window( this.close() ), it does not release the memory. I waited sometime to Garbage collector kicks-in, but nothing happened. I even tried calling GC.collect() but it doesn't work.

Why this memory not releasing? Is there any way to release this memory forcefully when i close this window?

Comment: If the memory did not collect when you forced it then those images are not elagable for garbage collection. You must have a refrence to them or a reference to the window holding them somewhere else in your code. Please include the code showing how you "close this window and open another"

Comment: How do you know that the memory isn't being released?

Comment: I simply use this code: MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(); mainWindow.show(); this.close();  And i'm look from task manager if memory released but it's not.

Comment: If Task Manager shows that your program's memory usage keeps increasing, then you probably have a memory leak. Other than that, Task Manager is not particularly reliable for telling you how much memory your program is using.

Answer (score -1):

I'm quoting from MSDN's documentation about [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/Apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image) class:

> "Large image files can impact performance because they load into
>   memory"

that means the app loads the images as application resources.

When it comes to application resources, the GC will not collect them due to the fact that they are technically "cached" for use in your application. (therefore, somehow being referenced.)